# New to Bootstrap: Struggling to get a Dropdown menu to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get the following bootstrap dropdown to work. I think I have referenced the correct scripts and css files, the top level shows but no dropdown appears when clicking on it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdown55">
                Marketing
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown55"><ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Return home">Brand</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Return home">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Return home">Market</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? What is the problem?

Comment: Have you any error in your inspector ? Because your html code works fine : http://www.bootply.com/MVz5D0VqqX

Comment: HiTheLittlePig - The top menu item is visible and formatted like your example in bootply but when I click on it, there is no dropdown menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are declaring the Bootstrap JS library twice.

`<script href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Pick one (minified is better unless you plan on editing it which I don't recommend) and remove the other.

You're conflicting that way.